# Spring Mobile - Interceptor not applied? Device is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mobile

I'm experimenting with Spring Mobile but I can't seem to get the basic example working.  I have a feeling I'm missing something stupidly simple but I can't figure out what it is. Here is what I have in place...

In web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param> 
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>deviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>deviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In applicationContext.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:device="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mobile/device"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mobile/device 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mobile/device/spring-mobile-device-1.0.xsd">

    <!-- Interceptors that execute common control logic across multiple requests -->
    <interceptors>
        <!-- Detects the client's Device -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor" />
    </interceptors>

</beans:beans>
```

In my Java class:

```
public class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {

    // So that we can lookup the current Device 
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        Device currentDevice = DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(request);
        if (currentDevice.isMobile()) // <-- fails here with NPE
```

**Why is the device not set and resulting as null?**

EDIT: 
Log files seem to indicate a problem with setting the interceptor but I'm still not sure where I went wrong.

> 2012-05-29 09:36:36,696 DEBUG [ConstructorResolver.java:201] : 
>   Ignoring constructor [public
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor(java.lang.String[],org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor)]
>   of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0':
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 1 of type
>   [org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor]: Could
>   not convert constructor argument value of type
>   [org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor]
>   to required type
>   [org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor]:
>   Failed to convert value of type
>   'org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor'
>   to required type
>   'org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor';
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert
>   value of type
>   [org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor]
>   to required type
>   [org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor]: no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a look at this and managed to get it to work myself. So I have a few comments.

1a) I don't think both the Filter and the Interceptor are required. [I've just used the Filter and that was enough](http://static.springsource.org/spring-mobile/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/device.html#spring-mobile-device-resolver-filter).

1b) The Interceptor (if used) [should be configured in a `DispatcherServlet` xml config file](http://static.springsource.org/spring-mobile/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/device.html#spring-mobile-device-resolver-interceptor). You look like you are using Struts from the use of `ActionSupport`, is this correct? If so, you (probably) won't have a `DispatcherServlet` and therefore I don't think this config will work as expected. I think that's why you're getting the stack trace.

2) I would add a breakpoint to `org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverRequestFilter.doFilterInternal` to make sure it's being executed.

3) I would check that Struts isn't doing something 'funny' with the `ServletRequest`, and hiding the ["currentDevice" request attribute](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mobile/blob/61c768b09d1a36a154b17de772ab3e3090251449/spring-mobile-device/src/main/java/org/springframework/mobile/device/DeviceUtils.java#L32) from you somehow. In fact, I would port your code to vanilla Spring if possible.

4) Maybe you could use [`ServletActionContext.getRequest`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.2.3/org/apache/struts2/ServletActionContext.java#ServletActionContext.getRequest%28%29) in your `execute` method and see if that works, and/or compare the returned request to that set in `setServletRequest`.

---

Using Spring MVC, this is what works for me. My project is called spring-mobile-test, and "spring-mobile-test" is its context root:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>deviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>deviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml is empty.

mvc-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="temp" />

</beans>
```

temp.TestController:

```
package temp;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.mobile.device.Device;
import org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public @ResponseBody
    String home(HttpServletRequest req) {
        Device device = DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(req);
        String msg = "";
        if (device.isMobile()) {
            msg = "Hello mobile user!";
        } else {
            msg = "Hello desktop user!";
        }
        logger.info(msg);
        return msg;
    }
}
```

The browser shows the following text when I browse to the URL `http://localhost/spring-mobile-test/mvc/`:

> Hello desktop user!

Comment: As I thought... it was a really stupid mistake that no one would have been able to determine here because I didn't post the entire `web.xml` contents. I had my filters setup backwards! Your suggestion #2 helped me set the breakpoint in the right place to realize my error.  And I believe I needed both the filter and the interceptor in order to get my application to work... at least in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Adding filter in web.xml is ample enough to handle mobile device etection.

1- Use Below config in web.xml file.

```
<!--Device Resolver filter start here  -->
<filter>
       <filter-name>deviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverRequestFilter     </filter-class>
</filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>deviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

2- Adding below jar file

```
        spring-mobile-device-1.x.x.RELEASE.jar
```

3- Code To check device

```
        Device device=DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(request);
        boolean isMobile = device.isMobile();
        boolean isTablet=device.isTablet();
```